Abilities of old (Intel) MacBook Pro to handle 4k external monitors
I have an old Intel MacBook Pro and need help understanding how much graphics power it has to handle external monitors.
I currently use my 2017 15in MacBook Pro (with Radeon Pro 560 4GB graphics) with two 27in 1080p monitors but need to upgrade them to 4K.
But I'm a bit worried my Mac might not handle them. When it's warm and when I have many windows open on different monitors, my Mac already runs quite hot, fans on full speed, and kernel_task eating up 500% plus processor power.
Could anyone with more experience educate me on whether my model could handle two external 4K monitors?

what is your specific question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post  ... this site is not for doing a poll of people's experiences

@jsotola  apologies if my question offended anyone, I'm genuinely trying to understand how many external monitors and at what resolution my old macbook can handle ... and couldn't think of a better site than this one to ask for people's expertise.   I'll try to reformulate the question

@jsotola I edited the question, please let me know if it's now acceptable or if I should change anything else. much appreciated!

What research have you done regarding this? System load and heat are factors unique to your situation and that we really cannot address. But the ability of this system's hardware to support specific hardware configurations should be published or known. So, have you done online searches to find what Apple says this system supports, or what other's have tried and tested?

From Apple's documentation regarding the system's capabilities:

Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
at millions of colors and:

Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
Up to four displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
Thunderbolt 3 digital video output
Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C
VGA, HDMI, and Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold separately)



Thank you for your answer, however, I was hoping for answers from user experience with similar setups, rather than what Apple says.  Of course, Apple tells me I should be able to connect two displays ... but often that's far from real life scenarios, so I was hoping to find people who may have similar setups who can share their experience.

I understand that, but this site isn't for that sort of discussion. For experiences and opinion, you will need to go to a forum where open discussion is the point and goal. Superuser is for specific questions that can be answered empirically. This is an empirical answer to your question. I recommend that you read through the Help section to better understand the goals and purpose of this site.
